# How to get bar chart with distinct count based on a column in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have the following data:

```
Name, Sport, Random Number
John, Tennis, 4
Jacob, Tennis, 4
Jacob, Tennis, 2
Jacob, Football, 5
```

I want to show a bar chart that counds up the number of People playing Sports.

```
X Axis: "Sport"
Y Axis: "COUNT(Number of Records)"
```

My current tableau is set as this:

```
Rows: Name
Column: SUM(Number of Records)
```

I want the bar graph to reflect the "Count of DISTINCT names who play the sports".
My problem with the above is that the "Tennis" for example has a count of 3 instead of 2. How do I make it so that the bar shows up as 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot get a distinct count of 2 dimensions combined, natively.
However what you can do is combine two dimensions and get a distinct count of that.

Create a calculated field `[NameSport]` with `[name] + [sport]` as the formula.
Then drop it on column and use `COUNTD(NameSport)`.

That should do the trick.